# how can I add React 18 to existing HTML?

Tags: html, reactjs

Here's my code attempt, it doesn't work. Here's my code: I can make it display using a lower version of React but that gives warnings in the browser console. I want to correctly implement adding React 18 to an existing HTML

```js
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

const myArr = [
    {
        Heading: "lorembdbfyhfhjvjvj",
        Body: "hdhdgbfb"
    },
    {
        Heading: "lorembdbfyhfhjvjvj",
        Body: "hdhdgbfb"
    },
    {
        Heading: "lorembdbfyhfhjvjvj",
        Body: "hdhdgbfb"
    }
]

const Reuse = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.Heading}
            {props.Body}
        </div>
    )
}

const MyDisplay = (props) => {
    const sense = myArr.map(v => {
        return <Reuse Heading={v.Heading} Body={v.Body} />
    })
    return (
        <div>
            {sense}
        </div>
    )
}
document.body.innerHTML = '<div id="app"></div>';
const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('app'));
root.render(<MyDisplay />);
```

```html
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

    
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hi</p>
    <div id="app"></div>

    
    <script src="./todo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a functional answer that works using ReactDOM.createRoot instead of ReactDOM.render

```html
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <p>Hi</p>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">

const myArr = [
    {
        Heading: "lorembdbfyhfhjvjvj",
        Body: "hdhdgbfb"
    },
    {
        Heading: "lorembdbfyhfhjvjvj",
        Body: "hdhdgbfb"
    },
    {
        Heading: "lorembdbfyhfhjvjvj",
        Body: "hdhdgbfb"
    }
]

const Reuse = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.Heading}
            {props.Body}
        </div>
    )
}

const MyDisplay = (props) => {
    const sense = myArr.map(v => {
        return <Reuse Heading={v.Heading} Body={v.Body} />
    })
    return (
        <div>
            {sense}
        </div>
    )
}
const container = document.getElementById('app')
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
root.render(<MyDisplay />);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```